# Python 3.4.3: Safe way to print unicode strings to a console?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unicode, console

When writing one-off scripts for file management, I am often using the `print` function to verify if e.g. the list of files I am operating on is what I intend it to be. Consider e.g.

```
for path in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
    print(path)
```

On Windows (including Cygwin when `LANG=C` is used, so this may apply to Unix too) this will raise an `UnicodeEncodeError`, if the file names include unicode characters.

In Cygwin, when using `print(repr(path))` instead, unsupported characters are escaped as `\uxxxx`. In the Windows console however, it will still raise an `UnicodeEncodeError`.

### Partial Solution

The closest things to solutions I found were

```
unicodestring = "Hello \u2329\u3328\u3281\u1219 World"

print(repr(unicodestring).encode("utf8").decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
# Breaks even supported characters

print(unicodestring.encode("unicode-escape").decode("ascii"))
```

both of which are rather verbose for "quick and dirty" scripts, especially when the print call consists of multiple strings with possible non-ascii content.

Similar questions exist for Python 2, but the solutions don't usually work with Python 3. Also, they are often equally verbose.

Comment: The quick and dirty answer would be `unicodestring.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')`. Encoding with one codec and decoding with another doesn't make sense. It's like encoding an image using PNG and decoding it as JPEG. Anyway there are plenty of better answers to your question elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Comment: The verbosity still remains an issue for quick-and-dirty scripts though. A full example with `print` (in python3 where `encode` doesn't return a string and hence is printed as binary-array literal) whould read `print(unicodestring.encode(sys.stdout.encoding,errors="replace").decode(sys.stdout.encoding))` which I already consider plenty long for a script maybe only a few lines long.

Comment: @kdb, for Python 3 you can use [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).